# Magento 2.2 override UI Component js file

Tags: magento2.2

Does a Magento ninja knows how to override this file :

vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/file-uploader.js

Which is referenced in :

vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml

```
<components xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_definition.xsd">
    ...
    <fileUploader class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader" template="ui/form/element/uploader/uploader"/>
    ...
</components>
```

Big thanks for any hints!